# DNSMASQ serve different dns results to different subnets

Tags: linux, dns, dnsmasq

In my network infrastructure I have multiple subnets intended to segregate different types of devices.  I would like the ability to serve different DNS responses from different DNS servers based on the requesting subnet.  For example I'd like to use Google's DNS for one subnet but say CloudFlare's anti-malware DNS for another.  I would also like the ability to then further lock down by using different "address" declarations on the different subnets.

One way that some people accomplish the first part is to use the "dhcp-option" declaration to serve different server addresses to the different subnets but this kind of defeats the purpose of DNSMASQ and turns it basically into just a DHCP server and also defeats using a firewall to restrict access to port 53 to control any hard-coded dns servers.

The other option I've seen is to run 2 instances of DNSMASQ however this creates a highly customized setup which doesn't allow any of the system level configuration files or run scripts which I'd like to avoid.

So I'm hoping someone can offer a solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. On a quick search I do not find this feature in DNSMasq so is this software absolutely mandatory. If you look at unbound, another recursive nameserver that can be authoritative on some records too, it has the feature you need, check for "View Options" in https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/documentation/unbound/unbound.conf/

Comment: So if I read the documentation on unbound "views" would allow redirecting specific domains to local domains by subnet but it doesn't appear that it would allow me to define different forward name-servers to each subnet.

Answer (score -1):

Presumably you want to all of the subnets to use DNSMasq to resolve local domain names, but you want the subnets to use different recursive resolvers for Internet queries?

You should be able to do that with the DHCP settings (so that each subnet will received two DNS entries - one for DNSMasq and one for another resolver e.g. 8.8.8.8).  These entries will end up in the /etc/resolv.conf for each device and will be attempted in order when the device needs to resolve DNS.  If DNSMasq is set to resolve local queries only, then the device will be forced to try the second address (e.g. 8.8.8.8) to resolve Internet queries.

Comment: Agree that this may address the issue but I lose capability to blacklist, cache and other advantages a caching name server provides.

Comment: Ah okay.  You want all queries to flow through DNSMasq (to use blacklisting, cache) but when DNSMasq is forwarding queries to resolving nameservers, you want to DNSMasq to choose 8.8.8.8 for queries originating from one subnet, and 1.1.1.1 when queries originate from another subnet etc.  From what I understand DNSMasq reads it's local /etc/resolv.conf to identify the upstream resolvers to forward queries to (but these can be set directly as well).  I don't think that you can specify a routing preference depending on the originating subnet for those queries (but I might be wrong)

Comment: But it may be possible to run two instances of DNSMasq on the one machine, have each instance listen for incoming requests on different interfaces and specify different upstream resolvers for those queries.

Comment: It may be possible to just run different dnsmasq instances on different ports and use some clever firewall rules to rewrite incoming port 53 traffic to forward it to the appropriate port. So you wouldn't need multiple interfaces.